# How do I call a collection of tables with normalized (generic) information

Tags: naming-convention

In a database design there are many fields with information that needs to be normalized. For instance for an address record countries can be normalized but also the address type (i.e. private address, billing address, business address). This leads to tables with information that, once implemented, only changes on a very occasional basis. What is the generic name to refer to these kind of tables?

Comment: I'd say `countries` and similar tables are often called ["reference"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_table) tables.

Comment: Or lookup tables.

Answer (score 0):

These are often referred to as code tables.  It is common that the primary key will be a short code which can be used as a foreign key in tables which use the data.  Theses tables may contain additional information as required.